# How to programmatically change the selected item and modify a view?

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-spinner

I have small problem.

I'm using Spinner in android. For example spinner contain 4 string items: Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4. Spinner is set by for example Item3. Now i wanna to programmatically change selected item to Item2 and change font color to red. So i did:

```
_spinner.setSelection(1);
View view = _spinner.getSelectedView();
if(view instanceof TextView)
{
    // change color
}
```

But it didn't work. It's because when i get selectedView, Item3 is still selected so i change color on Item3 view. How to fix it?

Comment: You describe bad example. when you set spinner.setSelection(2); it have to set item3, because 2 it is an index of item and count starts from 0. So maybe your approach is work fine?;)

Comment: Eugene - fixed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
spinner= findViewById(R.id.spinner);


        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                ((TextView) adapterView.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                ((TextView) adapterView.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(19);            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: I already have some OnItemSelecetedListener bu after that call method "setSelection" method onItemSeleceted is not called. I'am not sure (I'm no at home now) but I have View.OnItemSelcetedLister. I try change it to AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListerner when I'll be at home :)

Comment: Yes, it's work. I have already implement this listener but there were another problem ;)
Thank's for help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting adapter like this :

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list) {
        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                                    ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView tv = (TextView) view;

            if (position == 0)
                tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(Activity.this, android.R.color.darker_gray));
            else
                tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(Activity.this, android.R.color.black));

            return view;
        }
    };
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter );
    spinner.setSelection(Adapter.getPosition(Item2));
```

This way you can easily set different color for Item1,Item2 or Item3
and item2 will be dynamically set on spinner.